# Executive command/code if "access denied" error is displayed

Tags: windows, batch-file

How would I execute a command or commands if the error "access denied is displayed"?

something like this

```
del file 
if access denied goto :1
:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is just to see whether or not the file still exists:

```
del file 
if exist file goto :1
```

If you *specifically* want to detect only "access denied" and not other errors, you could save the error to a file, something like this:

```
del file 2>error.txt
findstr /c:"Access denied" error.txt && goto :1
```

(that code hasn't been tested)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `DEL` command will return an [`Errorlevel`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) of `0`, irrespective if the delete succeeds or fails for any reason. However, `DEL` command will display a list of the files deleted if [Command Extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) are enabled. Hence, using `FOR /F` [loop command against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html), next code snippet should work **for a single file**:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions
set "sOutput="
set "sFPFile=%cd%\file.txt"    :: Full Path to File
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('del "%sFPFile%" 2^>^&1') do set "sOutput=%%G"
if /I "%sOutput%"=="%sFPFile%" (
    echo Deleted file: "%sOutput%"
) else (
    echo An error occured: "%sOutput%"
    rem could be    "Access is denied."
    rem          or "Could Not Find ..."
    rem          or another error displayed
)
```

Should be improved a bit if `%sFPFile%` contains a wildcard character(s).